How to explicitelly set the wxFrame position?
Having such a simple wxFrame:
...
wxFrame* mainFrame = new wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "main frame", wxPoint(10, 20), wxSize(150, 100), wxICONIZE);
mainFrame->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(80, 50, 100));
mainFrame->SetSize(wxSize(200, 50));
mainFrame->SetPosition(wxPoint(1400, 200));
...

the SetPosition method call does NOTHING! (the frame stays at position set in the constructor: wxPoint(10, 20)).
When the wxICONIZE flag is omitted the SetPosition method do work as expected!
Why does setting the wxICONIZE flag makes the SetPosition NOT working?

Try mainFrame->refresh().

Side note : Why do you use new wxFrame? Avoid the use of useless use of new. If you find you do need to dynamically allocate, at least use std::make_unique instead of new. I

@user12002570 thx for suggestion but it doesn't helped!

@PepijnKramer Using new is normal(like OP is using for widgets) in wxWidgets. In fact, it is recommended/encouraged.

@user12002570 I can understand dynamic allocation (polymorphism). The new would only make sense if the api can implicitly take over ownership, which ofcourse is possible (specifically for a somewhat older api). So thanks for that feedback :)

@Dario101, are you under Linux with Wayland?

@AhmedAEK, no this is TLW - they don't have parents

@AhmedAEK Igor is right here - it's TLW and it gonna potentially be the ONLY one window in the app.

@PepijnKramer Yeah, i know the limited use of the dynamic allocation, but sorry, that's rather NOT the source of problem here.

@Dario101 I apologize for the digression. I never used wxWindows, but I see a Move method in the docs (wxFrame is derived from wxWindow so it should have it too)

@PepijnKramer No problem:-)

How do you expect SetPosition() to work on an iconized frame?
